# AWS Amplify phone number input validation - most practical method?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

```
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth';

        await Auth.signUp({
            username,
            password,
            attributes: {email, phone_number: phoneNumber}
        })
```

assume 'phoneNumber' is a user-dependent input.

many (most) inputs will cause failure.

What is the most practical method for validation of 'phoneNumber' prior to Auth.signUp ?

Additionally, why does failure manifest as such in React Native?:
[image]